# Can donate money I promised to donate during Ramadan to a friend who is in financial trouble?

Tags: ramadan, sadaqah

When I lost job because of my stupidity in 2008, I happened to promise a donation during Ramadan month. I started donating it to a school.

With the blessing of God, I was able to keep my promise until this year.
Now, I have met one of my classmates and found that he is in financial trouble. He has 2 kids.

Can I donate money to my friend this time? 
I am not related to my classmate.

Am I still keeping my promise if I do this?

Note : I am not MUSLIM. I just believe in God.

Comment: Is your friend Muslim?

Comment: No. He is not. Neither of us are MUSLIM and belong to same religion. I just believe.

Comment: AFAIK, there is a Hadith which says, breaking promises for a greater good is alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among Muslim scholars, it is preferred to do good to your closest of relatives and friends. So your relatives are closer to you than your friends, and your friends are closer to you than strangers, and believers are closer than non-believers. ([Arabic source](http://www.nabulsi.com/blue/ar/art.php?art=8081&id=44&sid=46&ssid=48&sssid=49))

So you start from your closest circle going to the bigger one.

> They ask you, [O Muhammad], what they should spend. Say, "Whatever you spend of good is [to be] for parents and relatives and orphans and the needy and the traveler. And whatever you do of good - indeed, Allah is Knowing of it." (Quran 2:215)

Answer (score 0):

You can give money to him as it is a good thing to help people. even not being  a muslim, keeping promises is good thing, but in this case, helping your friend is more important